# Mysql : Sort by id DESC but also sort by another column and ignore value 0

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Im trying to figure out if this is possible.

I want to sort by the id in DESC order, but there are certain records in the table that need to be pushed to the top. 
 I tried some ways, here is one ex. Maybe someone can help me out here?

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
ORDER BY CASE WHEN index >0
THEN index
END , id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But I cant seem to get the right output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost! Try this:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN index > 0
THEN 0
ELSE 1
END, id DESC
```

Comment: thanks! Little more modification I got it working the way I needed it. You rock